# Why .php files are are ignored in FF after update Ubuntu from 17.10 to 18.04?

Tags: firefox, php

I checked all relevant matter (as far as i know), **PLEASE give me some idea** how the problem can be fixed, i am blocked since one week.
only phpmyadmin disply is normal after reinstall<
note: 
all code including info.php is with long tags

```
 <?php ...  ?><br/>
**found in /etc/apache2/apache.conf**<br/>
on line 34:  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php<br/>
on line 35: include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf<br/>
<br/>
**found in `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`**<br/>
on line 5,6,7:<br/>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin><br/>
    Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch<br/>
    DirectoryIndex index.php<br/>
<br/>
**found in: `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf`**<br/>
<IfModule mod_dir.c><br/>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm<br/>
</IfModule><br/>
```

**output of  `php -v:`

```
PHP 7.2.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: May  9 2018 17:21:02) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

**output of  `php -m`**:

```
[PHP Modules]

 - bz2 
 - calendar
 - Core
 - ctype
 - curl
 - date
 - dom
 - exif
 - fileinfo
 - filter
 - ftp
 - gd
 - gettext
 - hash
 - iconv
 - json
 - libxml
 - mbstring
 - mysqli
 - mysqlnd
 - openssl
 - pcntl
 - pcre
 - PDO
 - pdo_mysql     
 - Phar     
 - posix     
 - readline     
 - Reflection     
 - session     
 - shmop              
 - SimpleXML     
 - sockets     
 - sodium     
 - SPL**
 - standard
 - sysvmsg
 - sysvsem
 - sysvshm
 - tokenizer
 - wddx
 - xml
 - xmlreader
 - xmlrpc
 - xmlwriter
 - xsl
 - Zend
 - OPcache
 - zip
 - zlib
 - [Zend Modules]
 - Zend
 - OPcache
```

Comment: Also, please use `code formatting` for all code and command output in your question! It is really unreadable otherwise, even if you "fix" (actually worsen) it with other formats. You also lose HTML-like tags without code formatting. Use the **`{}`** button in the question editor, or Ctrl+K.

Comment: I tried everything possible to solve the problem myself.  Since NO helpfu Ununtu-support is available i will try to  > reinstall LAMP > reinstall Ubuntu (older version e.g. 17.10)  > establish  server  on Win10 :(

Answer (score 0):

the problem that i was trying to explain is solved in a easy way, as follow:

i had to turn on the disply errors which were off after the update

in: /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini

```
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
```

then  the browser show an error due to a missing  long php opening tag in a subprogram